# Message Invalid column type: getBLOB not implemented for class oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CLongRawAccessor

Tags: java, oracle

I have a problem when trying to read blob from Oracle DB
by using this

```
rs.getBlob("ARCHIVE_REQ_FILE_BLOB")
```

I also tried this

```
oracle.sql.BLOB blob= (oracle.sql.BLOB) ((OracleResultSet) rs).getBlob("ARCHIVE_REQ_FILE_BLOB");
```

The following error appears

> SQL Message Invalid column type: getBLOB not implemented for class oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CLongRawAccessor

I use IBM WebSphere application server 8.5.5, open connection using WebSphere datasource using oracle oracle 11.2.0.2

Comment: with the following Error Code 17004 and SQL Stat 99999

Comment: please add it to the question, not in a comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are not trying to read a `BLOB` value.  You actually have a `LONG RAW` value in the database and you are trying to read that as if it were a `BLOB`.

I would recommend that you read the [Oracle documentation for reading data from `LONG` and `LONG RAW` values in JDBC](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/jstreams.htm#i1014085).  Oracle even provides example code to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

If your column is really a BLOB, then you need to make sure that in your Java code that you are not defining the column as a LONG_RAW (search for calls to defineColumnType) as this will make the server send the data as a LONG_RAW instead of a BLOB.

Answer (score 0):

in some cases solvable on an SQL level if the content is not too big for your use case:

```
select dbms_lob.substr( some_blob, 4000 ) as some_blob
from some_tab
```

depending on your Oracle db you can choose a higher value for `4000`, but for older versions this should work almost everywhere.
**sometimes `3500` is safer** because of unicode conversion of some chars to multiple 8-bit characters.

(the above shortens the blob content to 4000 characters, if necessary and converts the blob to some more suitable datatype)